# Windows Form app in Adminstrator mode

Tags: c#, winforms

I have windows form application which needs to be run in administrator mode with out editing the app.manifest file. Got the below codebut don't know where to place the code in windows form application.

```
    ProcessStartInfo proc = new ProcessStartInfo();
    proc.UseShellExecute = true;
    proc.WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
    proc.FileName = Application.ExecutablePath;
    proc.Verb = "runas";
    Process.Start(proc);
    Application.Exit();  // Quit itself
```

Comment: Why is making changes to the code "easier" than just making the manifest changes?

Answer (score 0):

Put this code inside you main form loading event

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            ProcessStartInfo proc = new ProcessStartInfo();
            proc.UseShellExecute = true;
            proc.WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
            proc.FileName = Application.ExecutablePath;
            proc.Verb = "runas";
            Process.Start(proc);
            Application.Exit();  // Quit itself
        }
```

Comment: so you want to run the application itself run as administrator not other application ?

Comment: Yes , I want run the application in administrator mode. how do I do it using c#

Comment: This will just keep the same things happening over and over again. I think what the OP has failed to ask for, and what your answer fails to provide, is the code that detects that the application is already running as administrator and so (in that situation) doesn't have to relaunch itself and exit.